# Selecting values by last date

Tags: mysql, date

I have table with several entries for one point, is it possible to show only last entry for each point?

Example

```
points |  date
A1       2016-02-12
A1       2016-02-15
A1       2016-03-12
B1       2016-01-11
B1       2016-03-15
B1       2015-09-28
C1       2016-01-28
C2       2016-03-03
D1       2015-12-12
D1       2016-01-12
E2       Null
E3       Null 
F1       Null
```

I want to get something like this, without ignoring Null values.

```
points | date
A1       12.03.2016.
B1       12.03.2016.
C1       03.03.2016.
D1       12.01.2016.
E2       Null
E3       Null 
F1       Null
```

I edited question because I tried group by and it didn't work for me( I forgot to mention before) It showed only entries with date, and I need points with null value as well
Something like this:

```
    A1       12.03.2016.
    B1       12.03.2016.
    C1       03.03.2016.
    D1       12.01.2016.
```

Comment: What are your researches? What did you try? Do you have a query we can revise? Do you want something like `group by`

Comment: Ok, to be fair Vipin Jain was correct with his answer. I tested it again and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get by using [MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) FUNTION

```
SELECT points,MAX(date) 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY points;
```

if you want to change date format you can use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function